# ScrollBar position in a update panel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I've got a problem with a scrollbar.

I've got 2 updatepanels. 1 that holds a gallery and other updatepanel that holds 2 buttons when button is clicked the pictures in the gallery change.

I've got a problem in my big gallery(holds more pictures) that when clicked on the button the scroll bar is reset to the top of the page and when you scroll down it takes forever so that page gets stuck when it tries to load the picture or repaint them (not sure).

I tried to look for a way to start the scroll bar in the position of the gallery so the user won't be needing to scroll down after loading the picture with the subject he wants to see, but after about a few hours looking for solution I gave up.

I'm using jQuery and ASP.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only targeting IE add MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback in your page declaration (or config file)

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

Otherwise you'll need to use script to target an element on the page - e.g:

http://blogs.x2line.com/al/articles/156.aspx

Comment: thank you i will try the link,i do need to be able to do that in other browsers too.

Comment: Edit: the link you gave me is not for ajax. its for a full refresh.

Comment: Instead of calling body onload hook in as this e.g.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1080903.aspx/1

Comment: i think im not using this right or it only work in IE. i dont see any changes in chrome